# Syntax error when merging pattern matching cases

Tags: ocaml

I coded the following function to compute the cartesian product of two lists.

```ml
let rec descartes a = function
| _ when a = [] -> []
| [] -> []
| t::q -> (List.map (function x -> t, x) a) @ (descartes q a) ;;
```

But when I want to simplify the function

```ml
let rec descartes a = function
| _ when a = [] | [] -> []
| t::q -> (List.map (function x -> t, x) a) @ (descartes q a) ;;
```

I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/expr.html) the syntax of pattern matching is:

```
pattern-matching ::=  [ | ] pattern  [when expr] ->  expr  { | pattern  [when
                          expr] ->  expr }
```

And you can find the syntax of `pattern` [here](https://www.ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/patterns.html). So as you can see `when` is not a part of `pattern`, which explains the syntax error.

But in any case, your code is redundant, once you have `[] -> []` you don't need `_ when a = [] -> []` anymore. So you can simply write:

```
let rec descartes a = function
    | [] -> []
    | t::q -> (List.map (function x -> t, x) a) @ (descartes q a) ;;
```